# Java. Как передать значения в параметрах get запроса через запятую

Tags: java, spring

Подскажите, как правильно сформировать параметр, чтобы в get запросе его передать, как method?sort=documentName,ASC&size=50&page=1

Сейчас почему-то в итоге запятая кодируется и получается так method?sort=documentName%2CASC&size=50&page=1

Comment: Каким способом вы делаете запрос (какое API используете)?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можете делать так: `...?sort=documentName&sort=ASC`

Spring будет поддерживать такой запрос.
В контроллере принимайте нечто такое:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(@RequestParam("sort") List<String> sortParams) {
    ...
}
```

Насчёт этих символов `%2C`, то это оооочень давняя проблема браузеров, с которой `Spring` хорошо справляется. Сейчас попробовал отправить запрос в метод с такой строкой `sort=documentName%2CASC` и `Spring` отлично отобразил параметры.

```
2022-04-14 10:03:49.858  INFO 21700 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] ru.***.controller.MController        : Params [documentName, ASC]
```